# Manga with a strong female lead (a princess) that likes to beat up (bad) people for fun (with her fists)

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's definitely **not** completed!

It's about a princess (I'm not sure about that but she is definitely a noble) that occasionally beats up people while only using her fists (she can use some type of magic that makes her stronger).

She is very pretty and usually has her hair up in a bun with a single strand of hair loose (on one side of her face). In the first chapter she literally punches an assassin head first into a wall.

The crown prince(?) takes interest in her after she beats up a room full of nobles at a banquet (she even piled them up). He thinks she is pretty funny. Her brother constantly stresses about her reputation (she has some nicknames... something like bloodstained princess, crazy dog - not that harsh but I can't remember it).

She beats up a dragon too. There's a slave (very cute) that she rescued; he can turn into a dog/werewolf?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please do include any more detail you can think of; the more you add, the easier it will be to find the right answer.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: I notice that you edited your question after my answer to indicate that the manga is not completed. As far as I can tell, the one I posted is still ongoing. It's also fairly recent, though. Did you read this within the last year or two?

Answer (score 5):

[*Saigo ni Hitotsu Dake Onegaishite mo Yoroshii Desu ka?*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/saigo-ni-hitotsu-dake-onegaishite-mo-yoroshii-desu-ka) or *May I Please Ask You Just One Last Thing?*

[image: Front cover of]

> The engagement between Scarlet, a noblewoman from a ducal family and the Second Prince Kyle was suddenly annulled during the ball. She had been falsely accused of harassing a girl called Terenezza, daughter to a baron, whom the Prince doted on heavily. Condemned by everyone around her, forced to burden all manner of crimes, she finally decided enough was enough. “Before I leave here, may I ask for one final thing?” As the crowd threw their boos and jeers, and that good looking guy flung his insults ─ Her palm spun like a drill and the ballroom floor was stained with blood.

Where she learns of her title of "Bloodstained Princess" (click to enlarge):
[image: Page where she gains the title of "Bloodstained Princess"]

On the next page, he informs her that she's also known as "Mad Dog Princess".

Found with a search for `manga "bloodstained princess"`